# Less than specified bytes of data from OBD

Tags: obd-ii, obd, elm-327

0100 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#Mode_1_PID_00) should provide 4 bytes of data. But there has been cases, like Audi A4 2.0 TDI, where the data from 0100 was less than 4 bytes. So is the data garbage? Or the data might contain zero(s) at the beginning of the string which has been omitted when sent from the ELM 327 OBD adaptor?

Comment: Do you have a raw dump of the data that you could share with us? Are you streaming the data in binary mode?